# jQuery Datatables+ sScrollY messes up column header width

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable that uses sScrollY for vertical scrolling in jquery tree structure. When the page initially loads, the column header width doesn't match with body width. However, when you sort the column, the width match up.

Here is the datatable code.

```
    oTable = $('#Customers').dataTable(
    {
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bAutoWidth":false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "sScrollY": "325px",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
        "aoColumns": [
                            { "sType": 'numeric' },
                            { "sType": 'html' },
                        ]
    });
```

Tried few options to fix, but it won't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling fnAdjustColumnSizing() after sorting, and also after resizing the browser (call it from a $(window).resize function).

That fixed similar issues for me.